# Python: Easy way to loop through dictionary parameters from a list of evaluated strings?

Tags: python, loops, dynamic

I have a dictionary created from a json file. This dictionary has a nested structure and every few weeks additional parameters are added.

I use a script to generate additional copies of the existing parameters when I want multiple "legs" added. So I first add the additional legs. So say I start with 1 leg as my template and I want 10 legs, I will just clone that leg 9 more times and add it to the list.

Then I loop through each of the parameters (called attributes) and have to clone certain elements for each leg that was added so that it has a 1:1 match. I don't care about the content so cloning the first leg value is fine.

So I do the following:

```
    while len(data['attributes']['groupA']['params']['weights']) < legCount:
        data['attributes']['groupA']['params']['weights'].append(data['attributes']['groupA']['params']['weights'][0])

    while len(data['attributes']['groupB']['paramsGroup']['factors']) < legCount:
        data['attributes']['groupB']['paramsGroup']['factors'].append(data['attributes']['groupB']['paramsGroup']['factors'][0])

    while len(data['attributes']['groupC']['items']['delta']) < legCount:
        data['attributes']['groupC']['items']['delta'].append(data['attributes']['groupC']['items']['delta'][0])
```

What I'd like to do is make these attributes all strings and just loop through them dynamically so that when I need to add additional ones, I can just paste one string into my list and it works without having another while loop.

So I converted it to this:

```
    attribs = [
        "data['attributes']['groupA']['params']['weights']",
        "data['attributes']['groupB']['paramsGroup']['factors']",
        "data['attributes']['groupC']['items']['delta']",
        "data['attributes']['groupD']['xxxx']['yyyy']"
    ]

    for attrib in attribs:
        while len(eval(attrib)) < legCount:
            eval(attrib).append(eval(attrib)[0])
```

In this case eval is safe because there is no user input, just a defined list of entries. Tho I wouldn't mind finding an alternative to eval either.

It works up until the last line. I don't think the .append is working on the eval() result. It's not throwing an error.. just not appending to the element.

Any ideas on the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure this will fix it, but I do notice one thing.

In your above code in your while condition you are accessing:

`data['attributes']['groupA']['params']['weights']`

then you are appending to

`data['attributes']['groupA']['params']['legs']`

In your below code it looks like you are appending to `'weights'` on the first iteration. However, this doesn't explain the other attributes you are evaluating... just one red flag I noticed.

Comment: Nah im just editing the actual values for example sake. Just a copy/paste typo. Ive corrected it above

Answer (score 0):

Actually my code was working. I was just checking the wrong variable. Thanks Me! :)